# Why is my question about motion controller input still closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a question a while back about detecting joy-con motion controls, and it was closed under the reason *Too Broad*.

However, I disagree with the close reason, and was wondering if it is off topic. And if it is off-topic, why so?

[How to detect joy-con input/motion controls in HTML5 JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814200/how-to-detect-joy-con-input-motion-controls-in-html5-javascript)

Comment: (Wasn't sure if this belonged in question so I'm commenting)On a side note, none of the 'Questions that may have your answer' answered my question, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable on-topic question to me.

Comment: You probably want to ask, why the question is still closed as “too broad” and not why it was closed in the first place. As your edits show, you understand quite well, why it was closed.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54814200/3) was the version of the question that was actually closed. Not saying that the current revision should be re-opened, or stay closed. But it's certainly different from that one.

Comment: It might've gotten closed because it's simply not feasible. JavaScript is limited to what the browser exposes to the programmer, joy-con motion controls might not fall within that area. Also, this might be browser-dependent, OS-dependent, etc. But not an expert in that area.

Comment: @ErikA then that should be an **answer**. Closing questions is not a system that is in place to indicate infeasibility of an idea, or to answer it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Agree, but look at it in the state it was when it got closed. When someone asks something that's borderline feasible at best, but shows no effort at all in the question, that's a quick close for me, because it often requires a pretty complex answer. The edits have substantially improved it, though, but I'm certainly not surprised it got closed

Comment: @ErikA agreed as well, without the code this question is a different story

Comment: The code is irrelevant to the question asked. The code doesnt make the question on-topic, it was on-topic before the code was added. A perceived lack of research is not a reason to close a question unless there is a duplicate readily available. That may be a reason to downvote a question, but this question does not seem deserving of downvotes.

Comment: Last I checked, it wasn't closed as off-topic, so that's a bit of a red herring.  IMO, the Too Broad closing, however, was very valid.  Now that there is more of an attempt, it's specific enough to be reopened.

Comment: Why? Because not enough people with the privilege to vote for reopening your question voted for it to be reopened.

Comment: @fbueckert how-to questions do not require attempts to solve the problem, nor is the code contained in the question an attempt to solve the problem. It is an attempt to assuage the delicate sensibilities of close voters who have no experience with the given technology. It is an example usage of the API for reference sake, and is not directly relevant to the question. The question was reasonably scoped and well defined before the code was added.

Comment: @Tiny Giant I knew the code wasn't super relevant, but yes I did add it so that people would stop flagging/downvoting it since 99% of questions without code on SO get flagged..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As it currently stands, your question is a valid candidate for reopening. You have reasons to believe the control should trigger events, the MDN documentation hints to that as well, and you have procured code with current behaviour as well as desired one. It is definitely not too broad anymore.

---

There is something that irks me in comments:

> It might've gotten closed because it's simply not feasible.

No offense meant, but that is misguided. Closure is not intended to answer a question. If the answer to a question is a simple "no, that's not possible", then the correct course of action is to **answer that**, along with supporting links to documentation.

Comment: Off topic, but where are you seeing the "MDN documentation hints to that as well"? There's no mention of motion controls in the linked MDN page.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin It says that an event should be dispatched when the user "moves an axis". Motion controls aren't mentioned *specifically*, but - assuming that we're talking about tilting a controller, here - I would think that they fall under that broad umbrella. Describing that as a "hint" that the control should indeed be triggering an event with the OP's code as it stands seems like a fair characterisation on Félix's part; nothing *explicitly* says "this API supports motion controls, not just thumbsticks", but it's a reasonable thing to expect after reading the docs.

Comment: @MarkAmery It's a little confusing, but those axes are for the analog inputs on the controller, not accelerometer inputs for motion control. I don't think the Gamepad API supports accelerometer inputs at all.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I believe this is not the best place to be sharing your expertise. Maybe consider adding an answer on the main question along with details, explanations of what you just said and links to the documentation? For you to be able to share your knowledge is precisely why we prefer for the question to remain opened.

Comment: The main point being that the documentation, while not explicitely saying "JoyCon motion detection is supported", gives enough information that people like us mere mortal, can be under the impression that it *should* be supported. If you actually know otherwise, you should be able to add an answer to that effect.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I don't think there's any information I can provide that would be news to the OP, given that they're the one that originally posted the link to the MDN page. I was however curious where you'd noticed relevant information in that page, because that would in fact solve the problem. Unfortunately it seems there is no such quick solution. My second response is to Mark explaining where the motion control stuff comes from, not "sharing my expertise" as you call it (I'm not an expert in this subject area).